# CDNs' page load testing by increasing JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, testing, cdn

I will test the CDNs at page load speeds according to location by increasing the JavaScript Code. But I could not find high-megabyte JavaScript code for testing. When I try to use small kilobyte or byte differences, the page load speed is not stable and load time differences are negligible. The project with Low-kilobyte JavaScript code can open slowly from the same project with high-kilobyte JavaScript code ect. Any suggestion ?

Comment: You could just take one of your smaller JS files and paste its content 3000 times in the same file. Bam, now you have a bigger file (which is still valid javascript)

Comment: Yes, I have tried this but load time differences felt like negligible and still not stable so.My task is to make chart about this subject and to see if increment of time make sense.

Comment: So, what's the problem then? Make progressively larger files, load each one N times, measure and chart load times.

Comment: "load time differences felt like negligible" - most likely, this is the effect of browser caching.

Comment: I got your point. Thanks for answer.